# Why simple FileInputStream line return exception?

Tags: java, apache-poi, fileinputstream

Button Action;

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  try {
  // TODO add your handling code here:
     deneme();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

File reading void;

```
public void deneme() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    try {
            FileInputStream file2 = FileInputStream (new File("D:\\Ornek.xls"));
            HSSFWorkbook workbook;
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file2);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFRow row1 = sheet.getRow(0);
            HSSFCell cellA1 = row1.getCell((short) 0);
            String a1Val = cellA1.getStringCellValue();
            HSSFCell cellB1 = row1.getCell((short) 1);
            String b1Val = cellB1.getStringCellValue();
            HSSFCell cellC1 = row1.getCell((short) 2);
            String c1Val = cellC1.getStringCellValue();;

            System.out.println("A1: " + a1Val);
            System.out.println("B1: " + b1Val);
            System.out.println("C1: " + c1Val);
                }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
                }


}
```

I take below exception when i debug it;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
```

Exception throwed by FileInputStream line. Am i missing something ?

Thanks.

**-- SOLVED --**

Sorry for silly question first:)

```
FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream (new File("D:\\Ornek.xls"));
```

`new` keyword missing at the beginning. Thanks to @dkatzel

Comment: Which line exactly throws that exception? Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Do you mean `new FileInputStream(new File etc)` there?

Comment: Related issue - if you have a File object, [pass that straight to Apache POI, do not go via an InputStream](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream). As [clearly explained in the docs](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream), using a file directly has a much lower memory footprint and is quicker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the `new` key word.

Try this:

```
FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream (new File("D:\\Ornek.xls"));
```

However that should be a compile error not a runtime error.

Comment: Ah you are right :( Strangly i have not compile error on line. Application work but turn exception.